# How to add a row in ms access database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add a data row on MS Access database using VB.Net code, but it seems not working, and it's not even giving me an error. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnComit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnComit.Click
    If inc <> -1 Then

        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

        dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Leaveform").NewRow()

        dsNewRow.Item("FullName") = txtFullName.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Department") = txtDepartment.Text

        ds.Tables("Leaveform").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)



        da.Update(ds, "Leaveform")

        MessageBox.Show("New Record added to the Database")

        btnComit.Enabled = False
        btnAddNew.Enabled = True
        btnUpdate.Enabled = True
        btnDelete.Enabled = True

    End If
```

Comment: How/where is the database?  is it part of the project or do you specify a path to it? `Dim rows = da.Update(ds, "Leaveform")` will tell you how many rows were affected.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Please do not tag c# if you are explicitly asking for vb.net.

Comment: Most likely it is working and you're just not looking for the data properly. As suggested, the result of the call to `Update` will tell you whether it worked. An exception means it failed, a zero result means there were no changes to save and a non-zero result means there were changes and they were saved. If you get a non-zero result, [read this](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx) to learn how to manage local data files.

Comment: You have not provided us with anything other than a code dump and a vague statement of "it seems not working, and it's not even giving me an error.".  Does you MessageBox appear?  Have you debugged the code to verify that the `If inc <> -1 Then` condition is true so that the code is run?